# starting a service at boot time taking too much time,why?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-service

I'm trying to build an app that starts an service which displays a View. What I am trying to do is to display the view quickly just after the boot but its takes too much time(>1min) to start the service.
My BroadcastReceiver:

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF)) {
        Intent intentservice = new Intent(context,NewService.class);
        try{
        context.startService(intentservice);
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } else if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON)) {
        Intent intent11 = new Intent(context,MainActivity.class);
        intent11.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    }
   else if(intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED))
    {      
       context.startService(new Intent(context,NewService.class));
    }
```

Manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
<service android:name="com.example.p.NewService"></service>
<receiver android:name="receiver.myReceiver"
android:permission="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED">
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.SCREEN_OFF" />
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.SCREEN_ON" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
</intent-filter>    
</receiver>
```

how to proceed? Is there any way to set priority or something like that?

Comment: I would assume that the problem is that your phone is doing lots of stuff right after the boot and there is just not enough resources for your app, so I actually don't think that there is any reliable solution to your problem. But just in case,  can you please post the code of your Service?

Answer (score 2):

Inside receiver replace permission with:

```
  <intent-filter android:priority="1000">
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
  </intent-filter>
```

This should speed up things.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it is faster than earlier but I want it to start before all other system app(like IME), means adding same priority(or more priority) like them.But according to [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/intent-filter-element.html#priority) it must be <1000. Is there some other way?